# Undefined Time Stamp format?

Tags: datetime, timestamp, datetime-format

I'm using an application that sends time-stamps that i cannot classify, for example:

1. **2014-11-01 20:42:17.677** i get **41944.8627038542**
2. **2014-10-28 23:25:23.000** i get **41940.9759570255**
3. **2014-10-29 19:28:53.000** i get **41941.8117242708**

And from the sequence from **2014-10-30** it would be **41942.xxxxxxxxxx**

Any idea what kind of time-stamp format is this?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of days (and fractional days) since 12/31/1899

Comment: If you check a [list of common epochs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) you can see January 0, 1900 there for (at least) MS Excel and Lotus 1-2-3. January 0, 1900 is December 31, 1899

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It was in fact 12/30/1899 in my case.